# Join year and julian day as a date column in R and plot it

Tags: r, date, plot, julian-date

I have some data with a column for the day of the year and another for year. As example, let's think in this dummy data:

```
temp <- rep(runif(730,15,40))
doy <- rep(c(1:365),2)
year <- c(rep(2015,365), rep(2016,365))
```

I would like to join doy and year as a date column (2015-365 format). Is it possible to deal with this date format? How ggplot or the basic function `plot` deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a Julian date to a Date object use the %j format.  For example:

```
temp <- rep(runif(730,15,40))
doy <- rep(c(1:365),2)
year <- c("2015","2016")

jdate<-as.Date(paste(year, doy, sep="-"),"%Y-%j") 
df<- data.frame(jdate, temp)

library(ggplot2)
f<-ggplot(df, aes(x=jdate, y=temp))
f+ geom_point() + scale_x_date(date_breaks="6 week", date_labels="%Y-%j")
```

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e. Unfortunately, as.Date(jdate, "%Y-%j") return date formats 2015-01-31. It seems as.Date doesn't accept "%Y-%j" format. Could be that true?

Comment: Mmm, good. Thanks for that. It solves the issue of plotting in the date format I need. And it is almost 70% of the problem. Is there a way to store Julian date format (yyyy-ddd) in column?

Comment: Yes, use the format function to convert the date object into a character string.  Like this format(jdate, "%Y-%j").